# Laravel relation from a pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a relation that I cant figure out my current application looks like this

**Models**

```
User.php
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }
```

```
Team.php

    public function tournaments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tournament::class);
    }
```

```
Tournament.php

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }
```

**Tables**

```
tournaments
id
```

```
teams
id
```

```
team_tournament
tournament_id
team_id
```

Now a tournament can have just some of the users participate in the tournament so I've created the below

```
team_tournament_users
tournament_id
team_id
user_id
```

To store users that are participating in a tournament from the team.

How should this look in terms of eloquent relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So taking your team_tournament_users, I would do the following

Would use the naming convention **participants** of tournament, so table name would be `participants` instead of team_tournament_users

**Migration**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateParticipantsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('tournament_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('team_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary(['tournament_id', 'user_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('participants');
    }
}
```

**Relationships:** Then would define the following relationships in models

```php
class User extends Model
{

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }

    public function tournaments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tournament::class, 'participants')
            ->withPivot('team_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}


class Tournament extends Model
{

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }

    public function participants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'participants')
            ->withPivot('team_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}

class Team extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function tournaments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tournament::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

> How would I then go about retrieving all the users participating in the team for a specific tournament? So if 3 users/members from a team are selected for the tournament how can I easily find out which members from that team are selected?

```php
//There's already a relation between Tournament and Team(s)
//So we can use it to get the tournament participants from the team

$t = Tournament::with('participants')->first()
  ->participants
  ->groupBy(function($participant){
    return $participant->pivot->team_id;    
  });

//If Team with an id of 5 has members participating in the tournament
//Then we can get the members of Team as
$team = Team::findOrFail(5);
$t->get($team->id);
```

Comment: How would I then go about retrieving all the users participating in the team for a specific tournament?

So if 3 users/members from a team are selected for the tournament how can I easily find out which members from that team are selected?

Comment: @Paradigm Have updated my answer in response to your above comment

Comment: Thanks I've marked your answer as correct, thanks for the help.